# Which kind of error scenarios are handled by Zone in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, exception

In angular 2, ExceptionHandler is used to handle errors. But some errors are also handled by Zone like: TemplateParseError and InvalidPipeArgumentError.

1. What kind of errors are handled by Zone?
2. How to identify error List which are handled by Zone?

Comment: What makes you think `TemplateParseError` or `InvalidPipeArgumentError` are handled by Zone? It would also be interesting why this is relevant to you.

Comment: Zone is just a function that wraps the Angular application. Everything in Angular runs within a Zone. That Zone is mentioned in a stack trace doesn't mean Zone handles an exception.

Comment: I identified it from Error Stack Trace at console. Both of these errors are handled by zone. I would like to identify which errors are handled by exceptionHandler and by Zone so that i can create custom exception handler class.

Comment: Then please at least post the stack traces that you think indicate that the exception is handled by the zone.

Comment: Can you please tell me who handle TemplateParseError and InvalidPipeArgumentError?

Comment: If you build the component that causes this error dynamically, then wrapping the call that creates the component with `try/catch` should do. If a component added statically to your project causes this error, then you can wrap the call to `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` with `try/catch`.

Comment: [It contains stack trace of error for template parse error. This error is not handled by ExceptionHandler][1]


[It contains stack trace of error for accessing property of undefined. This error is handled by ExceptionHandler][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjbvo.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lunym.jpg

Who is handling Template Parse Error?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean. The exception is shown in the browser console because the exception is **not** handled at all.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. But ErrorHandler also prints the error on console. And this is only class in Angular2 which handles exception.